# How do I dynamically load an assembly that is built from a previous interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a .net Winform App that is trying to dynamically load an assembly but is getting an ReflectionTypeLoadException exception

The App includes two references to P.DLL and C.DLL (code is below)
Then dynamically loads SI.DLL ( code to load is below )

Here is the code for **BEFORE** my problem started

***P.DLL contains this***

```
public interface iP
{
    string Version { get; }
}

public class P : iP
{
    public P()
    {
        Version = "4.0";
    }

    #region iP Implementation
    public string Version { get; private set; }
    #endregion
}
```

***C.DLL contains this***

```
//
// C.DLL
//
public interface iC : iP
{
    // no interface changes here
}
public class C : P, iC
{
    public C()
    {
        // this class does stuff but is irrelevant to problem except it is the inheritance chain
    }
}
```

***SI.DLL contains this***

```
//
// SI.DLL
//
public interface iSI : iC
{
    // no interface changes here
}

public class SI_Engine : C, iSI
{
    public SI_Engine()
    {
        // this is the object in the SI.DLL assembly that I am trying to load
    }
}
```

So essentially SI (interface iSI) derives from C (interface iC) which derives from P (interface iP)

```
SI (iSI) : C (iC) : P (iP)
```

So with the above code, I can dynamically load SI.DLL and there is no problem.

***This is the code in my App that dynamically loads the SI.DLL***

Here is the code that calls the loader:

```
bool bLoaded = false;
iC retval = LoadPlugin<iC>(fullPathAndFileName, out bLoaded);
```

This is the function that does the loading:

```
    public static T LoadPlugin<T>(string fullPathAndFileName, out bool loaded)
    {
        loaded = false;
        T retval = default(T);

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fullPathAndFileName);
        if (assembly != null)
        {
            Type pluginType = typeof(T);


            // this is where I am getting the ReflectionTypeLoadException

            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

            // Method 'TimeTrial' in type 'SI.SI_Engine' 
            // from assembly 'SI, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
            // does not have an implementation.
            //

            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (type.GetInterface(pluginType.FullName) != null)
                    {
                        retval = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                        loaded = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

***CHANGES***

I have changed P.DLL by adding a new interface, deriving from the old one, and implemented the function in the P class:

```
public interface iP
{
    string Version { get; }
}

public interface iP4 : iP
{
    bool TimeTrial();
}
public class P : iP4
{
    public P()
    {
        Version = "4.0";
    }

    #region iP Implementation
    public string Version { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region iP4 Implementation
    public bool TimeTrial()
    {
        return Version == "4.0";
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I have changed C.DLL to use derive from the new interface as well:

```
public interface iC : iP4
{
    // no interface changes here
}
```

With the changes to P and C:

SI (interface iSI) derives from C (interface iC) which derives from P (interface iP**4**)

```
SI (iSI) : C (iC) : P (iP4)
```

I made the changes, recompiled P.DLL and C.DLL and my application.
Now when I run the application I try to load an instance of SI.DLL that was built using the **OLD iP** interface and I get the exception.

My question is how do I dynamically load an assembly that is built from a previous interface?

Comment: The 'best' approach in my opinion would be to version your old iP and iC interfaces and load them all in. Then, when writing iSI you can inherit from the appropriate version and have no issues.

Comment: You may look into MEF though, to see if you can figure out how to dynamically choose which version of assemblies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

Comment: An old example: http://andrassebo.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-change-module-dll-in-runtime.html

Comment: Cory - doesn't versioning interfaces / dlls kind of defeat the purpose of an interface?

Comment: Well, sort of.. but so would using a older version of the same interface. I always hate to assume people's use cases, but if you have access to all 3 then you would want to recompile them all. However if you're trying to allow 3rd parties to create plugins, you'd either need to avoid changing the interface or design it in such a way to allow both versions to run.

Comment: The only sense using an interface is to guarantee properties/methods exist. If the interface goes and changes.. then you've broken the contract.  If this is something that is foreseeable, it'd be best to design it differently from the start.